# Determine the end of the Captivate slide?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe-captivate

I'm using Flash to call in a Captivate 5.5 file and control everything through Flash. I can control just about everything in Captivate just fine, but the only thing I need to figure out is how to tell if the current slide is on the last frame.

In Flash I have a "Next" button that will advance the Captivate project when clicked, but I want to hide the button until the Captivate slide is complete. I can use `MovieClip(_swfLoader.content).rdinfoCurrentFrame` just fine and it works perfect, but `MovieClip(_swfLoader.content).rdinfoFrameCount` gets the frames for the whole project and not just the slide the user is currently on.

I thought maybe I could access Captivates slide duration in seconds, but that is a no-go as well :( I cannot believe Adobe did not create a variable that will give developers access to any type of slide duration or slide completion.

One thought I have is to create some type of loop that would loop the current frame count and when the frames match, then the end of the slide has happened and make the "Next" button visible. But, I'm thinking the loop happens faster than the frame progression, so any type of frame count will match the current frame.

Another idea I had is check if the current pause state of Captivate is true (meaning Captivate is paused). In each Captivate slide I have a pause at the end of every slide to prevent automatic slide progression, but I couldn't find a way to check the pause status.

Has anyone ever ran into this issue? How did you over come this?

Here's a couple links to Captivate AS3 variables:

[CPGURU](http://www.cpguru.com/adobe-captivate-5-system-variables/)

[PIPEWERKS](http://pipwerks.com/2010/08/23/complete-list-of-variables-for-adobe-captivate-5/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could read those values and compare (found on CPGURU):

`rdinfoFrameCount` and `rdinfoCurrentFrame`

I haven't checked this though,

re the pause isn't it the `rdcmndPause` or `rdcmndPaused` property that pauses the slide?

Comment: Hey Lukasz, that was my first approach, but `rdinfoFrameCount` will count all the frames in the project when all I need are the frames in one slide. `rdcmndPause = 0` or `rdcmndPause = 1` will pause and unpause the slide, but when I try to call `rdcmndPause` (leaving out the value) I always get true. So there is no way to read the pause state.

Comment: I really think creating a loop in Flash (AS3) that will compare the current frame number to a previous frame number when the loops last ran. But, my problem is a loop will run many times before Captivate advances to the next frame.

Comment: depending on how much influence on the captivate file is in your hand you could inject some functionality into it by using some SWF's that can communicate with your wrapper, e.g. you could add a swf that will be placed at the end of each slide.

Answer (score 0):

I decompiled a Captivate SWF using SoThink and studied the XML script generated using
trace( [importedSwfRef].movieXML ) after importing the Captivate swf into my main AS3 Flash Movie.

- Each of the slides are in a movieclip
- You can see that the number of frames (XML Attr) of each slide corresponds to each movieclip
- Each movieclip is in its own layer
- Each clip is named 'SlideX_mc' Remember that slide number start at ZERO.
- It would seem that all slides are 'switched off' and the current Slide is 'switched on'

Physically adding a widget at the end of each slide is the 'hammer-head' approach. You wouldn't want to do it 100 times and it also requires a certain level of expertise on the side of your client to on-develop any content. Ideally you want a script that sniffs out and adds a stop() to each slide clip on the fly before commencing using addFrameScript()

JUST HAD A THOUGHT - Maybe you can add stop() to the end of each slide clip? You know the number of Slides so you could Loop through Slide0_mc to SlideX_mc querying the number of frames and then adding a Callback function to Stop(); the play head - Maybe?